# Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'. New to Gradle

Tags: grails, gradle

I am new to Grails 3 and Gradle. I am working to update an application 2.4.4 to Grails 3.2.8. With the upgrade I would like to build a plugin from scratch. I having trouble including it into the project using the standard way of declaring a dependency.

I am attempting to build grails-shiro plugin using gradle. I am running into the following error when running `gradle tasks`

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.spring.dependency.management', version: '0.5.2.RELEASE']
>Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.spring.dependency-management']
>Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'.
```

Here is a link to the project : 
https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro

I assume the main project to build would be located either in the shiro2 or shiro3 directory.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm also encountering this error when trying to update a plugin.

Comment: I was able to fix this by running : `gradlew tasks`
Looks like a discrepancy with the gradle versions.
More info can be found here: https://github.com/jlstrater/grails-spring-restdocs-example/issues/3