# Issues with Apache Shiro plugin, Grails 2.4.4 upgrade to 3.2.8

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, shiro

Upgrading Grails from version 2.4.4 to 3.2.8. Plugin declared not being resolved.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:shiro:1.2.1"
    ...
}
```

Grails attempted to find the dependency in the maven repo then at repo.grails.org.

Is there a different location to look for the grails shiro plugin?

```
Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins.shiro:1.2.1
Searched the following locations
    file:/C:/Users/Owner/.m2/repository...shiro-1.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Owner/.m2/repository...shiro-1.2.1.jar
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.2.1/shiro-1.2.1.pom
    ...shiro-1.2.1.jar
```

I am also attempting to build the plugin myself but running into issues with gradle and a dependency. [Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'. New to Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506245/new-to-gradle-could-not-create-task-of-type-dependencymanagementreporttask)

I attempted to include spring-security-shiro but it creates ready made login/auth functionality and haven't figured out a way around it. See below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install the Grails 2 plugin but that doesn't work in Grails 3.x - you have to use Grails 3 plugins (see http://plugins.grails.org/).

But there is no Shiro plugin for Grails 3. Some work was done to upgrade it, but that wasn't finished and there's no plans that I know of to make a Grails3-compatible version.

Comment: Thank you!! I gave it a try, however because I am updating a project I don't need the 'pre made' starter code that spring-security-shiro povides and I haven't figured out how to work with/around the ready made code. What would be the best way to work through this? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Would it be better to stay on 2.4.4? Or would I be missing out?

Comment: The upgrade to 3.x can be painful but will be worth it - at some point you won't have the choice and the longer you wait, the more painful it's going to be. Note that the spring-security-shiro plugin is a 'bridge' plugin between Spring Security and Shiro to allow you to use both, but both need to be configured and the plugin has very little functionality of its own. Your best bet is to use spring-security-core - there are a lot of experienced users out there who can help with whatever problems you have.

Comment: Also, note that none of the code generated by the spring-security-core is required - it's just starter code for the typical workflows but you can configure everything yourself if you want. Plus it's just 3 domain classes and a few lines of config, so it's hardly a burden on your app. Sign up for the Grails Slack at http://slack-signup.grails.org/ to ask more detailed questions

Comment: How do I work around the base configuration of Spring Security and customize? Can you recommend a decent tutorial? Thank you.